# Writing into pdf - Xref stream using incremental update

Tags: pdf, stream

What is wrong in the pdf on attached in link below, 
I have appended the new xref stream to this pdf using incremental update. Can anybody please let me know whats going wrong? u can decode the stream and verify all offsets are good, still no pdf viewer is able to render it.

http://www.filedropper.com/autolayoutmodified

Comment: I need to add a second signature to a signed PDF (using tcpdf) using incremental update. Can you explain what should i add to the file? I already read this: https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/DigSig/Acrobat_DigitalSignatures_in_PDF.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The startxref pointer points to a numeric value `3006` followed by an `obj` token and an additional numeric value `0` instead of an indirect object definition.

`3006 obj 0` should be `3006 0 obj`

Comment: hey @Setasign I did that change but still adobe acrobat reader is not able to read it..here is new link http://www.filedropper.com/temp_1 for pdf

Comment: I guess the stream is not passed to a predictor function.as defined in its DecodeParms, isn't it?

Comment: No, It is passed to PNG UP predictor and then compressed with zlib deflate.

Comment: What about the Length value? 16 seems to be much to less for the stream content. Anyhow ignoring the Length value will still end in problems decompressing the data. You should omit the predictor function and parameters to check if this is also a problem (I still guess).

Comment: Excluding png up filter and just compressing data with zlib...is working fine. but the question remain as it is, that why adobe acrobat reader is not able to deal with png up predictor though MAC's preview support it

Comment: Length fixed, too? Anyhow our implementation isn't able to uncompress the whole bytes because of a problem when the data is passed to the predictor function, too. Are you writing the predictor byte in every row?

Comment: well I tried changing the length to encoded data length but there is no change seen. and yes. I am writing predictor byte (02) at the start of every row.

Comment: look at this http://www.filedropper.com/temp_4 pdf now...still not able to open it with adobe acrobat reader. :(

Comment: created new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29770321/not-able-to-open-pdf-in-adobe-acrobat-reader , please check