# Not able to open pdf in adobe acrobat reader

Tags: pdf, stream, acrobat

I have modified one pdf appending the xrefstream using incremental update http://www.filedropper.com/temp_4 , which is opening fine with Mac's preview app, but not able to open it with adobe's acrobat reader, why is that so...?
Special request to Acrobat reader developer to respond on this.

Comment: Neither Mac's preview app nor Adobe reader are PDF format validators.

Answer (score 1):

The EOF markers are strange: `%%%EOF` and `%%%%EOF` instead of `%%EOF`. When chaning the last marker to `%%EOF` the file is read by Acrobat.

Anyhow the /Length value is still wrong `19` should be changed to `20`.